# QPainTextEdit add wave line

Tags: qt, qplaintextedit

I've working on a small SQL IDE App which is a neat tool for writing SQL procedure for Oracle & DB2. I'm using Qt 4 as the GUI base. 
Still I want to add instant grammar check function for My SQL IDE, it will write a wave line under the SQL code with grammar error,just like the VS2010 and eclipse. But I really don't know how to deal with this function. 
I've using the QPlainTextEdit for the document edit class.
I'd appreciate if you can give some tips and hints!
Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [QSyntaxHighlighter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qsyntaxhighlighter.html). It consists of code example on how to use it. Also QPlainTextEdit has chapter [Using QPlainTextEdit as an Editor](http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/qplaintextedit.html#using-qplaintextedit-as-an-editor). Another thing that may become useful for you is [Syntax Highlighter Example](http://doc.qt.digia.com/stable/richtext-syntaxhighlighter.html)